# JRuby not finding gems from GEM_HOME

Tags: rubygems, jruby

I am running jruby from the jar like this:

```
java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.6.jar
```

I installed pry with the following command-line:

```
GEM_HOME=~/jruby java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.6.jar -S gem install pry
```

This worked and I can see the gems under `~/jruby/gems` (the `~/jruby` directory didn't exist before running the above command). I can also see it listed:

```
$ GEM_HOME=~/jruby java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.6.jar -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

coderay (1.1.0)
ffi (1.9.10 java)
method_source (0.8.2)
pry (0.10.1 java)
rake (0.8.7)
slop (3.6.0)
sources (0.0.1)
spoon (0.0.4)
```

However, I can't get any of these gems to be recognized:

```
$ GEM_HOME=~/jruby java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.6.jar -e "require 'pry'"
LoadError: no such file to load -- pry
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at -e:1
```

I found that `gem env` dumps the default `GEM_PATH` and I can see my `~/jruby` listed under it. I am sort of a newbie with Ruby itself, so not sure if I am missing something obvious?

Comment: JRuby uses java paths.  Have you tried using the fully qualified path instead of ~ ?

Comment: I saw gem env expand it properly, but you have a point, I should try with full path.

Comment: OK, I just tried with full path instead of using `~` and it still didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I had `jruby 1.7.19` installed on Mac via Brew, so did a bit of experimentation. Interestingly, this works: `GEM_HOME=~/jruby java -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/Cellar/jruby/1.7.19/libexec/lib/jruby.jar  -Djruby.home=/usr/local/Cellar/jruby/1.7.19/libexec org.jruby.Main`, but this doesn't: `GEM_HOME=~/jruby java -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/Cellar/jruby/1.7.19/libexec/lib/jruby.jar  org.jruby.Main`, so the only difference is the `jruby.home` property and having a valid path makes `GEM_HOME` work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$LOAD_PATH`, in your ruby script such as

test.rb:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift '/home/root/captureJ/jruby-9.2.9.0'

require 'pry'
```

Comment: That didn't help when I tried with JRuby 1.6.6. However, beginning at least from version 1.7.27, this issue can no longer be reproduced.